# How to select correctly in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I have a table containing a list of image related tags.

See the details here in this screenshot:

[image]

What I tried:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM wallpaper_tag as a, wallpaper_tag as b 
WHERE a.tag = 1 
  AND b.tag = 2 
  AND a.wallpaper = b.wallpaper 
ORDER BY wallpaper 
LIMIT 10000
```

This SQL query works fine for me. But is there a better option?

I want to get a list of wallpapers if two tags match at the same time.

Comment: I speak english with google translate

Comment: If I find a better answer, I'll rephrase the question in a nice way.

Comment: the question is very good and has the right to life

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you actually want is all the `wallpaper`s with `tag`s `1` and `2`, you can do it with aggregation:

```
SELECT wallpaper 
FROM wallpaper_tag
WHERE tag IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY wallpaper 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tag) = 2
ORDER BY wallpaper 
LIMIT 10000
```

If the combination of `wallpaper` and `tag` is unique, the `HAVING` clause may be simplified to just:

```
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: your answer is more like me, i need time to understand

Answer (score 1):

I'd use an explicit join:

```sql
SELECT a.*
FROM wallpaper_tag as a
INNER JOIN wallpaper_tag as b
ON a.wallpaper = b.wallpaper
WHERE a.tag = 1 AND b.tag = 2
ORDER BY a.wallpaper
LIMIT 10000
```

I prefer this syntax as it makes it clearer what tables are joined and how they are joined.

Comment: thanks for your attention, is it possible to further simplify the query to the database?

Comment: What do you mean by "simplify"? If you mean efficiency then no, there is no way that query would be more efficient.

Comment: i mean to simplify sql query. If I only need the wallpaper_tag.wallpaper column

Comment: provided that we select from the same table, is it possible to shorten the sql query?

Comment: if it is not possible to speed up the sql query anymore, then I will declare your answer correct